# Foreground service not running when App exits

Tags: java, android, foreground-service

How can I keep the foreground service running even when the user quits the app?
I've tried running the service in another process, but the service still stops after I quit the app.
My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Test"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <service
        android:name=".Service"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:process=":service"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity
        android:process=":activity"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Service.java:

```
public class CountdownService extends Service {
    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    private String createNotificationChannel(String channelId, String channelName) {
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
        return channelId;
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    @NonNull
    private Notification getNotification() {
        String channelId = createNotificationChannel("id", "name");
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
        return builder.setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(PRIORITY_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .setContentText("Content Text")
                .setSubText("Sub Text")
                .setContentTitle("Content Title")
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startForeground(1, getNotification());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in MainActivity, I start the service like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
startForegroundService(intent);
```

I found that this application has only one process 'service' in the phone settings, but there is no 'activity' process, what is the problem? thanks.

Comment: "I found that this application has only one process 'service' in the phone settings, but there is no 'activity' process" - Isn't this expected behaviour when running a foreground service after closing the activity?

Answer (score 0):

Define what you mean by "exit."  If you mean they go into recents and swipe the app away, or go into settings and force quit, no.  That's the user saying "I want this app to end".  That will kill all services.  Something that could run even when the user says it shouldn't is basically malware.